# why adding order by in the query changes the aggregate value?

Tags: vertica

Following `vertica` example from https://www.vertica.com/docs/11.0.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/AnalyzingData/SQLAnalytics/AnalyticFunctionsVersusAggregateFunctions.htm?tocpath=Analyzing%20Data%7CSQL%20Analytics%7C_____2

```
CREATE TABLE employees(emp_no INT, dept_no INT);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES(1, 10);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES(2, 30);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES(3, 30);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES(4, 10);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES(5, 30);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES(6, 20);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES(7, 20);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES(8, 20);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES(9, 20);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES(10, 20);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES(11, 20);
COMMIT;
```

If I run this query without `order by`, I get same count value for all rows

```
dbadmin@b006bc38a718(*)=> 
select 
  emp_no
, dept_not
, count(*) over (partition by dept_not) as emp_count 
from employees;
```

```
 emp_no | dept_not | emp_count
--------+----------+-----------
      6 |       20 |         6
      7 |       20 |         6
      8 |       20 |         6
      9 |       20 |         6
     10 |       20 |         6
     11 |       20 |         6
      1 |       10 |         2
      4 |       10 |         2
      2 |       30 |         3
      3 |       30 |         3
      5 |       30 |         3
(11 rows)
```

But if I add `order by`, I get incremental value

```
dbadmin@b006bc38a718(*)=> 
select 
  emp_no
, dept_not
, count(*) over (partition by dept_not order by emp_no) as emp_count 
from employees;
```

```
 emp_no | dept_not | emp_count
--------+----------+-----------
      2 |       30 |         1
      3 |       30 |         2
      5 |       30 |         3
      1 |       10 |         1
      4 |       10 |         2
      6 |       20 |         1
      7 |       20 |         2
      8 |       20 |         3
      9 |       20 |         4
     10 |       20 |         5
     11 |       20 |         6
(11 rows)

Time: First fetch (11 rows): 85.075 ms. All rows formatted: 85.139 ms
```

What is the affect of `order by` ? Why do I get incremental value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the window clause only contains `PARTITION BY`, it returns the total sum of the *partition*  - for each row of the partition the same value.

If the window clause contains both `PARTITION BY` and `ORDER BY`, it returns the *running count within the partition* . So, using the `ORDER BY` expression, how many rows have been counted so far within the partition.

That's exactly how window functions work. They give you a whole world of possibilities ...

Comment: ok. while there might be value in providing a way to get running count, I feel that using the phrase `order by` isn't the best option and causes confusion. It seems running count is a side-effect of `order by`

Comment: and `partition by` seem to be same as `group by`. Wondering why not use phrase `group by` rather than `partition by` because `partition` has a another meaning in Vertica.

Comment: Yes, Manu - but if you go `SUM(amount) OVER(PARTITION BY iso_ctry ORDER BY sales_dt)`, you get the running sum of your sales per country over time. And that is actually handy ...

Comment: GROUP BY returns one row per `GROUP BY` column list combination, reducing the rows. `PARTITION BY` returns all input rows, but can return the same result for all rows in a partition. That is two very different use cases.

Comment: am I correct that I use analytical function over aggregate function if I need an output value for each input row?

Comment: Eg. I ran `select *, (sell_price-avg_for_neighborhood) from (select property_key, neighborhood, sell_price , avg(sell_price) over (partition by neighborhood) as avg_for_neighborhood from property_sales ) as ps;` from the property_sales example to compare each house price with average price - https://www.vertica.com/docs/11.0.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/AnalyzingData/SQLAnalytics/WindowsWithALogicalOffsetRANGE.htm?tocpath=Analyzing%20Data%7CSQL%20Analytics%7CWindow%20Framing%7C_____2

Comment: That's what I wanted to point out ... - or also, when you want to calculate the percentage of a value based on the sum of the partition

Answer (score 0):

That happens because Vertica applies a default `frame-clause` which is defined as:

```
RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
```

So to get the result you want, you may want to add the frame clause as below after you `ORDER BY` in the `OVER()` clause:

```
ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
```

This behaviour is documented as:

> If the OVER clause omits specifying a window frame, the function creates a default window that extends from the current row to the first row in the current partition.

[Link to doc](https://www.vertica.com/docs/9.2.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Functions/Analytic/window_frame_clause.htm)