# order by not returning running count

Tags: vertica

In this question - [why adding order by in the query changes the aggregate value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69905031/why-adding-order-by-in-the-query-changes-the-aggregate-value/69906237?noredirect=1#comment123600516_69906237) - I was told that "If the window clause contains both PARTITION BY and ORDER BY, it returns the running count within the partition . So, using the ORDER BY expression, how many rows have been counted so far within the partition."

Referring to this example - https://www.vertica.com/docs/11.0.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/AnalyzingData/SQLAnalytics/ReportingAggregates.htm?tocpath=Analyzing%20Data%7CSQL%20Analytics%7CWindow%20Framing%7C_____3

Why does the cumulative count shows `4` (last value of count) for all values of `sal=109`?

```
=> SELECT deptno, sal, empno, COUNT(sal)  OVER (
->   PARTITION BY deptno ORDER BY sal
-> ) AS COUNT 
-> FROM emp;
 deptno | sal | empno | count 
--------+-----+-------+-------
     10 | 101 |     1 |     1
     10 | 104 |     4 |     2
------------------------------
     20 | 100 |    11 |     1
     20 | 109 |     7 |     4<-
     20 | 109 |     6 |     4<-
     20 | 109 |     8 |     4<-
     20 | 110 |    10 |     6<-
     20 | 110 |     9 |     6<-
------------------------------
     30 | 102 |     2 |     1
     30 | 103 |     3 |     2
     30 | 105 |     5 |     3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You order by `sal`, which is at `109` for 3 rows within `deptno` 20. For the ordering criteria, there are 3 rows that should appear at the same time. After all 3 are added, after `100` for 1 row, you are immediately at 4. So you get `4` for all 3.

You need distinct ordering values to get distinct running count results.